# OAuthException code 100

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm getting the error:

`{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"C0VqQrGq4iM"}`

I manually built the login flow with the resulting dialog url:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=970056533030026&auth_type=rerequest&scope=email&display=popup&redirect_uri=https://www.opentable.ie/my/oauth/facebook`

On our FB app settings we have:

- App Domains has `opentable.ie`
- On Advanced Settings - Valid OAuth redirect URIs we have `https://www.opentable.ie/my/oauth/facebook`

When I went back to see my logs I saw that redirectUri lost https and is using plain http, that's the only pointer I have.

Any ideas on why we get this error? Thanks guys

Comment: HTTPs doesn’t get “lost” by itself; most likely your application is making an extneral redirect from HTTPS to HTTP somewhere for some reason.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, it was the load balancer actually, it worked locally. Thanks